# ¿Por qué no me muestra el optionMenu?

Tags: android, menú, actionbar

tengo un `Activity` que extiende de un `ListActivity` y no logro que me muestre el `ActionBar`. Este es el codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> Personas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<String> Personas= new ArrayList<>();
    Personas.add("Carlos");
    Personas.add("Belen");
    Personas.add("Liz");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Personas);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: en el manifest tengo:
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
y en style 
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159021/actionbar-not-working-when-extending-listactivity) de Stack Over Flow en ingles, los `ActionBar` solo se permiten en temas "despues" de Holo.

Tu `style.xml` es :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Pasalo a :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
```

Recuerda que en java no se admite la herencia multiple por lo tanto no puedes heredar de `ListActivity` y `ActionBarActivity` a la vez.

Comment: Hola, lo solucioné desde el Manifest <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">.
Gracias, saludos!

Comment: Excelente! Un saludo bro @LosMilton